# Merge entries in map if value equals key

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a std::map with the following values:

> 2 31
>   4 36
>   5 29
>   6 24
>   24 49
>   25 83
>   29 63
>   36 42
>   42 79

Now I want to "merge" values if a key exists for a value.
So the desired output (data structure is irrelevant) would be:

> 2 31
>     4 36 42 79
>     5 29 63
>     6 24 49
>     25 83

I have tried iterating through the map and using std::find for every value. But I am having problems with vector sizes greater than 3 and it seems to be very slow for large maps. Here is a small example not giving exactly the desired output:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    std::map<int, int> my_map = { {2, 31}, {4, 36}, {5, 29}, {6, 24}, {24, 49}, {25, 83}, {29, 63}, {36, 42}, {42, 79} };

    std::vector<int> temp_vec;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> destination_vec;

    for (auto it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it) {

        std::map<int, int>::iterator map_iterator = my_map.find(it->second);
        if (map_iterator == my_map.end()) {
            temp_vec.push_back(it->first);
            temp_vec.push_back(it->second);
        }
        else {
            temp_vec.push_back(it->first);
            temp_vec.push_back(it->second);
            temp_vec.push_back(map_iterator->second);
            // I stopped here because I could try another if loop here or a while loop for the whole process but it seems very inefficient
        }
        destination_vec.push_back(temp_vec);
        temp_vec.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove temp_vec. Just destination_vec.emplace_back(std::vector<int>{that, and_that}).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your map cannot link smaller values (as `{{1, 42},{2, 1}}`).

You might use:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> foo(std::map<int, int> m)
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> res;

    while (!m.empty())
    {
        auto it = m.begin();
        const auto key = it->first;
        auto& v = res[key];

        while (it != m.end()) {
            auto value = it->second;
            v.push_back(value);
            m.erase(it);
            it = m.find(value);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/sCukmR)

complexity is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Isn't m.erase hella inefficient? Because it's copying all values after the erased it?

Comment: @Dimfred: `map::erase` has amortized constant complexity (`map` is node based, not contiguous memory as `std::vector`).

Comment: Yep just looked it up. Thought it is n. Nvm mind then.